Application not running on azure cloud
I have deployed an ASP.NET Core 6 project on Azure cloud app service using Microsoft Visual Studio "publish", but when I open the deployed app, I keep getting

HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

I tried to run the .dll from the Azure console to get the full error message it returns

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

These are the web.config and appsettings.json on the deployed machine
web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\app-core.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v6.0.417" sku=".NETFramework,Version=V6.0.417" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: d997d705-03bb-4182-8868-507e5d3cc0a1-->

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnect": "dbConnectionString"
  }
}

I'm using both of them in my local project and they are working fine.
I also tried this solution gacutil is not recognized on Azure console although .NET SDK is installed

In your web.config file under handler tag add this arguments=".<LocalWebAppName>.dll .\app-core.dll".

I tried a simple ASP. NET 6 Core web application and deployed it to Azure App Service through Visual Studio, and it was successful.
Upon using your Web.config file in Azure, I encountered an error. Subsequently, I added my web app name to the Web.config file as shown below:
 </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\<LocalWebAppName>.dll .\app-core.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />

Below is my complete web.config file.
web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\kasampleapp.dll .\app-core.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v6.0.417" sku=".NETFramework,Version=V6.0.417" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: <Guid>-->

Azure App Service Output:


app-core is the app name and its already included
